# IPv4 connectivity to IPv6-only host

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I have a IPv6-only host (let's name it S) in my home network which is accessible from outside by its IPv6 address. Since my ISP doesn't provide any IPv4 connectivity, it cannot be accessible from IPv4 networks (e.g. from C). This host offer HTTP and HTTPS services. I have a dual-stack host outside from my home network and I want to use it as a proxy to get IPv4 connectivity to S such that it can be accessible from C. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the protocol, and you didn't provide much details. Usually something like [haproxy](http://haproxy.org) will work. There is good [documentation](http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/resources/making-content-available-over-ipv6/) for the opposite situation (making content on an IPv4-only server available over IPv6) on the [ISOC Deploy360 website](http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/) that you can use as a starting point. Just reverse the IP addresses.

A simple example based on that documentation:

```
global
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    log /dev/log daemon

defaults
    timeout client 5000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout server 10000

listen webserver1
    bind 192.0.2.1:80
    mode tcp
    server webserver1 2001:db8:abc:123::cafe:80
```

The IPv4 address is the address of your dual-stack server and the IPv6 address is the address of the IPv6-only server.

Comment: I wanted to use it for HTTP and HTTPS. Your solution works well. Thanks a lot! :-)